Is useful Shor factorization really practically feasible?
INTRO TO THE ISSUE. After studying this beautiful math concept many years ago, I recently revisited Shor's algorithm for factoring integers and its implications for RSA encryption. This time, I needed to plug in some numbers and, as a result, came across a few puzzling estimates. Could anyone help me figure out whether I’m missing something here or if my reasoning is flawed for some reason?
Here's my thought process:

Shor’s factorization algorithm is based on the Quantum Fourier Transform (QFT) — fine.
Modern secure RSA keys are at least $n=1024$ bits long.
The QFT involves very small phase shifts, with the last gate for an $n$-bit calculation requiring $\Delta\phi=\pi/2^{n-1}$. This phase shift becomes absurdly small as $n$ increases. For instance, for $n=1024$, the last gate shift would require $\Delta\phi\approx 3\times 10^{-308}$ radians... an unimaginably small angle.
Now, this is not just an abstract (though incredibly small) number. Going beyond math, if we want to perform this calculation for real, this $\Delta\phi$ must be implemented in a physical system existing in the real world. To achieve such a phase shift, we would need to (any useful alternative?!) evolve a qubit for a time $\Delta t$ at a detuning $\Delta E$, according to $\Delta\phi=\Delta E\cdot\Delta t/\hbar$. Achieving such a small $\Delta\phi$ implies a very small $\Delta E$ and/or a very small $\Delta t$. Let's optimistically assume a lower bound for $\Delta t>1$ picosecond (which is already crazy fast, probably well beyond achievable but let's not be conservative here). This would still lead to an incredibly tiny detuning $\Delta E<\hbar\Delta\phi/\Delta t\approx3\times 10^{-330}\,{\rm J}$
If this number wasn’t absurd enough, I tried - for the fun of it - to estimate how stable a quantum state would need to be to even vaguely calibrate such an energy. The corresponding lifetime $\tau$ required for this energy precision to make sense... is about $\hbar/\Delta E=10^{-12}\,{\rm s}/\Delta\phi$, which equates to roughly $10^{295}$ seconds.

In conclusion, it seems that to break a 1024-bit RSA key, we would need phase gates with an absurdly small $\Delta\phi$, in turn leading to a detuning $\Delta E$ far beyond any realistic scale. And the lifetime $\tau$ required to even just quantify this tiny detuning in the phase gate is "only" about 278 orders of magnitude longer than the age of the universe. So this universe is far too young to even start talking about such a small energy.
QUESTION. Am I missing something, or are these numbers actually correct? And, if they are correct, is it even remotely feasible to do such a calculation? These are the most absurd/shocking numbers I ever came across in my whole life... :)
SOME (unsatisfactory) SELF-ANSWERS I HAVE CONSIDERED:
A. Quantum Error Correction (QEC) can fix this. I think QEC is amazing, but this problem seems astronomically beyond its capabilities. Is it really feasible to implement such an insanely precise phase-shift gate? If anyone can pull this off, they would have created the most precise energy measurement tool ever conceived. This would overshadow the awe of cracking RSA, and by many orders of magnitude...
B. Approximate or alternative algorithms might still yield useful factorizations. This is intriguing, but these absurdly small numbers appear even when $n$ is around 100, with the corresponding $\tau$ already approaching the age of the universe. Given that the scaling with $n$ is THE critical issue here, I am wondering if we can really expect that — even when we are likely going to completely lose control of phase shift gates after the first few dozen bits out of 1024 — the algorithm can still produce anything useful.
Please, if you have any insights or could point me toward papers or studies that have addressed this issue... it would be fantastic. I assume I’m not the first person to think about all this.
PS I am very fine with blue-sky/crazy ideas... my puzzle stems form the fact that some seem to claim that RSA breaking by quantum computers is just around the corner (10-20-30 years?). I guess they mean they want to do it for real. So I am just wondering if I am missing something here...

Would you agree that Shor factorization is essentially about hitting that large number with a "hammer", then analyzing what frequency/frequencies that number resonates in?

I am not following the exact math correspondence, but yes the analogy makes sense to me... would this analogy clarify if the thing is more or less feasible to implement for real? or more or less solvable even if the actual procedure is approximate?

Factorization being a diophantine problem, at first glance it would seem that approximation may not work well... e.g. 17.05 being a real factor usually says nothing(?) about what the correct integer factors will be...

Yes, puzzling. I am sure somebody has an answer. However ok, even if I am able to just "probe" the result of my hammering at an imprecise level, I might learn something. Not obvious how useful indeed. I am a bit disturbed by the fact that it would be SO imprecise: I mean, in my understanding even controlling a pi/2^20 phase shift is not a joke. And this is a (exponentially) far cry from n=1024.

All this reminds me the story of the wise man and the king... the rice and the chessboard story. But the chessboard had only 64 squares :)

For controlling the $\frac{\pi}{2^{20}}$ phase shifts, have you taken into account that if 20 qubits can be used to encode those $2^{20}$ subdivisions, then some clever sensing method may possibly be used afterwards to deduce the phase shift from those 20 qubits? Is the sensitivity still absurdly implausible if using 20 qubits, by your calculations?

This might indeed be a way out: if every single two-level system only needs to implement a phase shift pi or not much smaller, then I see no obvious problem. Honestly, I have no clue, but it might solve part of the issue. This would be a sort of binary encoding for discrete dephasing: I have always been disturbed by the continuous nature of dephasing gates. I wonder if there is any reference about Shor implemented using similar multi-qubit for every line in the QFT. Seems tricky though.

You can use many qubits and a lot of gates to approximate it in different fashions, but according to https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.08168, "there is still no satisfactory method to realize arbitrary controlled rotation."  Interesting.

Well, just looking at the rate of progress in practice, the experiments are factoring maybe 5-6 bit numbers, improving at a rate of perhaps a bit per decade. So, with 10,000 years more effort, 1024 bits may become feasible ツ

you might find further relevant discussions in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shors-algorithm See for example https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5048/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15195/55

(this replaces an earlier, incorrect answer- thanks to HiddenBabel for pointing it out)
Thanks for the interesting question!
As you suggested, the answer is that we can safely ignore these exponentially small phase shifts without affected the answer much. Crucially, the precision required only grows very slowly-- logarithmically-- with the length of the input. This is explored in the following paper: Scalability of Shor’s algorithm with a limited set of rotation gates. I will quote the key part of the abstract:

Consequently, we study in detail the effect of using only controlled
rotation gates with $d$ less than or equal to some $d_{\text {max }}$.
It is found that integers up to length $L_{\max }$ $=O\left(4^{d_{\max}}\right)$
can be factored without significant performance penalty
implying that the cumbersome techniques of fault-tolerant computation
only need to be used to create controlled rotation gates of magnitude
$\pi / 64$ if integers thousands of bits long are desired factored.
Explicit fault-tolerant constructions of such gates are also
discussed.


I can also give a rough idea of the general reason why the above "has" to be true. The QFT, being an efficient algorithm, has a polynomial number of gates. Therefore, when you throw away exponentially small terms, you are throwing only away a polynomial number of them, which is still small. As a result, the difference between the target unitary and implemented unitary due to this truncation is bounded and small. You can find a more detailed treatment of this general bound in sec. 6.2.1 of Preskill's QC notes: https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/quantumcomputers/literature/preskill_1_to_6.pdf
